# Exception in template

Tags: c++, templates, exception

I tried to compile this code and I receive no complain. However, when I run it , it give me an exception error for the last line i.e. cout<<"Norm:"<

Could you please guide me how I can solve this problem. Thank you in advance

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using namespace std;

template<typename R,typename D> 
class GenericFunction
{
private:
    boost::function<R (D)> f;
protected:
    GenericFunction(){};
public:
    GenericFunction(const boost::function<R (D)>& myFunction){f=myFunction;};
    R evaluate(const D& value) const{cout<<"Good Job"<<endl;} ;
    R operator ()(const D& value);// const{ return f(value); };
}; 
template <typename R, typename D, int N>
class ScalarValuedFunction:public GenericFunction<R,boost::array<D, N>>
{
public:
    ScalarValuedFunction(const boost::function<R (const boost::array<D, N>)> &myF){};
};


template<typename Numeric, std::size_t N>
Numeric Norm(const boost::array<Numeric , N>& Vec)
{
    Numeric Result=Vec[0]*Vec[0];
    for (std::size_t i=1; i<Vec.size();i++)
    {
        Result+=Vec[i]*Vec[i];
    }
    return Result;
} 

double test(double t)
{
    return t;
}

int main ()
{
    const int N=4;
    boost::array<double, N> arr={0.2,  .3,  1.1,  4};
    ScalarValuedFunction<double, double, N> myfun(Norm<double,N>);  

    cout<<"Norm:"<<myfun(arr)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not forwarding the function argument to the constructor of the base class:

```
ScalarValuedFunction(const boost::function<R (const boost::array<D, N>)> &myF)
    : GenericFunction<R, boost::array<D, N>>(myF) // <=== ADD THIS
{
} //; <== SEMICOLON NOT NEEDED AFTER A FUNCTION DEFINITION!
```

Without doing this, the `GenericFunction` subobject will get initialized to the default constructor (which is accessible to the derived class because it is declared as `protected`), and its member variable `f` will also be default-initialized.

Then, when trying to invoke it inside `operator ()` (whose definition I suppose is the one you have shown in comments), Ka-Boom.

Comment: +1. You've beat me to it. And get rid of semicolons after function bodies. That's hideous.

Comment: @user2085646: This is the second question I answer about the very same project. Will you consider accepting at least one? :-)